# Why is the variable name "1stName" changed to "1 stName"?

Tags: vba

When I try to enter this: `1stName.Additem ()`, a space is put between the `1` and `st`, so ends up like this: `1 stName.Additem()`.

Answer (score 4):

Identifiers in VBA must begin with a letter: You can't have a legal variable/object name that begins with a digit. Rename your variable to `FirstName` instead of `1stName`.

Comment: There are also other restrictions. [This](http://virtual.parkland.edu/kcouch/CIS122/Week2/Exercises/goodname%20badname%20answers.htm) may prove useful reading